# Name conversion is not defined

Tags: python

I have an error when running the following in python

> Runtime error 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 6, in 
>     File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\rpy2\robjects__init__.py", line 55, in 
>       conversion.ri2py = default_ri2py
>   NameError: name 'conversion' is not defined

this is my script *init*.py

```
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
import rpy2.robjects.conversion

conversion.ri2py = default_ri2py
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'conversion' is not defined` means that python cannot find the variable you are talking about. Your code does not define `conversion` at any point. Did you perhaps forget to append `as conversion` after `import rpy2.robjects.conversion`?

Answer (score 0):

Variable simply not defined. Use the snippet below to define it.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.conversion.ri2py = default_ri2py
```

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/robjects_convert.html